# What does the 'a' part of standard form equation of a curve represent

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves

> The maximum point of a quadratic curve is $(-2,-5)$. The curve cuts the $y$-axis at $-13$. Find the equation of the curve. Give your answer in the form $y = ax^2+bx+c$.

For this question I learnt I had to use the standard form $f(x)=a(x−h)^2+k$ first. Then the general form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ of the equation of a curve.

What does the 'a' part of standard form equation of a curve represent. I understand that the '(x−h)2+k' is a sort of reversal of the result of when you use the completing the square to find the turning point of the curve but what does the 'a' part represent.

I have completed the question, I am just curious.
I have only finished GCSE so if the answer could be "dummed" down that would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think it would be helpful to explain in what context you have encountered this problem. In addition, it would make our task a lot easier if you could explain what you tried already and where are you getting stuck so we can guide you properly.

Comment: Do you understand what a parabola is, and what are its equations, and what the equations actually represent? [Wikipedia on Parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) is a good place to start.

Comment: This feels like a perfect use for the Desmos graphing calculator. Are you familiar with it? It will allow you to  graph the parabola, and give you "sliders" for each of $h, k$, and $a$ parameters, and let you see how the curve changes as you change the parameters.

Comment: Here, [try it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sxjnmc8m4v)!